# Why does .Where() on an IQueryable return a different type based on whether a Lamba or Func<T,Tresult> are passed as parameters

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, linq-to-entities

In my Entity Framework Code First project I have a repository object which contains routes

```
public class EFRepository
{
    ...
    public IQueryable<Route> Routes
    {
        get { return context.Routes; }
    }
   ...
}
```

If I run

```
var routes = this.repository.Routes
                  .Where(r => r.DeployedService.IsActive.HasValue 
                   && r.DeployedService.IsActive.Value);
```

The routes object is of type `IQueryable<Route>`.

However, if I run

```
Func<Route, bool> routeIsActive = r => r.DeployedService.IsActive.HasValue 
                                      && r.DeployedService.IsActive.Value;
var routes = this.repository.Routes.Where(routeIsActive);
```

The routes object in this case is of type `IEnumerable<Route>`.

I would have thought that they would be evaluated the same but clearly I am wrong.  What is the difference between the two statements and why do they return different types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method `.Where(Expression<Func<Route,bool>>)` is defined by `IQueryable<Route>`. The method `.Where(Func<Route,bool>)` on the other hand is defined by `IEnumerable<Route>` and not by `IQueryable<Route>`. Thus each returns its own type for fluent LINQ method chaining.

The additional method defined by `IQueryable` allows the expression tree to be pushed down to the LINQ provider, e.g. LINQ-to-entities, for lazy late evaluation at the provider level where this is possible.

Answer (score 4):

Because passing `Func<Route,bool>` will make it Linq-to-objects (`Func` is .NET delegate which will be executed in .NET code). It tells EF: load all routes and I will do filtering in .NET code.

You need to pass an expression (`Expression<Func<Route,bool>>`) which will be internally translated to SQL to work with Linq-to-entities. It tells EF: here is the filter I want to translate to SQL and execute on the database server and I want to receive only filtered result set.

Comment: In plain terms, with a `Func` the `Where` will be executed client side (so the whole table will be dloaded and then the restriction will be applied), with an `Expression` the `Where` will be executed server side (and translated in SQL)

Answer (score 2):

`IQuerable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`. This means that `Where` is overloaded:

One overload takes an expression and returns an `IQuerable<T>`.

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
```

The other overload takes a function and returns an `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
```

If you pass in a lambda, both overloads are applicable, and overload resolution prefers the first one. If you pass in a `Func<T,bool>`, then only the second overload is applicable.

If you change the type of your variable to `Expression<Func<Route, bool>>`, then you'll get an `IQueryable<Route>` back.